# how to port forward openshift pod with all of its ports?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, portforwarding

I'm using openshift `port-forward` to connect to a remote pod containing a few services.
How can I port forward all of the pod's ports to my machine?

Comment: Do mean multiple ports? Or do you expect that all opened ports are detected automatically?

Comment: Detected automatically. I don't want to explicitly modify the script for any new port (service) added

Answer (score 2):

You can consider kubefwd. follow the link for more details

https://github.com/txn2/kubefwd

Answer (score 0):

openShift supports port forwarding as well. Read this [manual](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.1/nodes/containers/nodes-containers-port-forwarding.html). And more explicit [example](https://blog.openshift.com/openshift-connecting-database-using-port-forwarding/)

> You can use the CLI to forward one or more local ports to a pod. This
>   allows you to listen on a given or random port locally, and have data
>   forwarded to and from given ports in the pod. Example:
>
> Use the following command to listen on ports 5000 and 6000 locally and
>   forward data to and from ports 5000 and 6000 in the pod:

```
$ oc port-forward <pod> 5000:6000

Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:5000 -> 5000
Forwarding from [::1]:5000 -> 5000
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:6000 -> 6000
Forwarding from [::1]:6000 -> 6000
```